# Xamarin forms; How to access the label from xaml.cs class of a rg.plugins pop up page?

Tags: popup, label

I have a label in my rg.plugins popup page and I want to change the text color of the label when doing an action.

I try to add an id to the label in xaml, but that is not possible. Is there any way to change the label text color from xaml.cs class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample code would help understand what the issues might be. I assume by rg.plugins, you're referring to: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup so I will answer accordingly.

It *looks* like it takes standard xaml and displays that in a dialog type popup. Your options for styling should be the same as any other:

1. Change color directly in xaml. `<Label Text="This is some text" TextColor="Blue" />`
2. Change it via a binding. `TextColor="{Binding ColorThatIWant}"` Where the page's BindingContext has been set to an object that has a public property or binding property of `ColorThatIWant`. Don't forget to implement `INotiftyPropertyChanged` if you want forms to react to property changes.
3. Set the value in code behind. `MyLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Blue;` where the label has a name value set. `<Label x:Name="MyLabel" Text="This is some text" />`
4. Use style dictionaries to set the value. `<Label Text="This is some text" Style="{StaticBinding MyLabelStyle}"/>` with a style of:

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

Comment: can you tell how to set the text color programmatically?
I tried like this: sms_label.TextColor = "5abcd7";

Comment: @SreejithSree  TextColor is a Color type, not a string, so you would have to do sms_label.TextColor = Color.FromHex("FF6A00"); Also, you have to set the x:Name property in the xaml for the label. This will only work in the code behind.

Comment: I don't know why I forget the x:Name property, big fool I am. Thanks for the tips of setting the color programattically.